# Converting 'labels' of matrices to matrices in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to write a short Matlab code to perform a certain mathematical function. The code generates a vector H which has entries of either 1, 2 or 3 (and size dependent on other factors). (In my mind), the numbers 1, 2 and 3 correspond to three particular matrices. Once my program has calculated H, I would like it to be able to multiply together all the matrices represented by its entries. To clarify, if H = [1 2 3 2], I'd like my code to calculate A*B*C*B. What is the simplest way of doing this? I thought about creating a vector with entries that are matrices, and using a function that gives the product of the entries of the vector, but I couldn't get that to work (and don't know if it can work - I'm very new to Matlab).

Ideally I'd rather not rewrite the rest of my code - if there's a way to get this to work with what I've done so far then that'd be great. I'm looking for functionality as opposed to slick coding - it doesn't matter if it's clumsy, as long as it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@zuloos answer might be problematic if the sizes of matrices are not the same - especially if number of rows are different. Should work if you put the matrices in cells.

```
 matrices = {A,B,C,D};

 result = matrices{H(1)};
 for i=2:numel(H)
   result = result * matrices{H(i)};
 end
```

Comment: Curly brackets are for "cells". Unlike matrices you can put pretty much anything in a cell - in your case it might be neccesary. If you store it like @zuloo it is required that all matrices have the same size.

Answer (score 0):

put all your matrices in another matice then you can use values of H as a the key to choose the right matrice `matices = [A, B, C, D]`. you would then go throug `H` one by one and multiply it with the result of the last operation. you will start with a diagonal matrice of the same dimensions as the other matrices and multiply this in each round of the loop with the matrice in `matrices` coreesponding to the value of `H`

```
matrices = [A, B, C, D]
// d is dimension of your matrices (i guess they are square)
erg = diag(d)
for i=length(H):1
   // supposed your matices are 2d
   erg = matrices(H(i),:,:)*init
end
```

i dont know if it makes sense here to multiply each step from left (like you would do in openGL) but i thought this allows you split up the operation in steps (like its done in openGL)

Comment: i have to refresh my matlab syntax skills for precise code... this may take some minutes

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand. Do you mean something like:
for i = 1:size(H)
    if H(i) = 1
       matrices(i) = A etc?

Comment: you put your matrices ordered in a new "array" which in matlab is a matrice, then you loop through H and get the correspondig matrice and multiply it with the result from the last step. you would have to initialize your result with a diagonal matrice (so X*DIAG = X)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help - I accepted the other answer since it works if the matrices are different sizes (and because he/she has less reputation)